# MySQL. Wrong order by json fied containing utf-8 string

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a field `title` of type json that contains translations for different locales. It looks like

```
{'en'=>'Title', 'uk'=>'Заголовок'}
```

I'm trying to order records by a translation

```
select id, slug, title->>'$.uk' as locale_title from blog_posts
order by locale_title
```

It works for `en` locale with Latin symbols but for `uk` (Ukrainian) locale with Cyrillic symbols I get the wrong order like `і, а, б, я`. 
For other text fields (not json) ordering works as expected `а, б, і, я`

**Additional info**

Mysql version: 5.7.25

database collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the collation of database and the collation of json operators are different:

```
collation(title->>'$.uk') //utf8mb4_bin
collation(other_field) //utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

To fix my problem I should set `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation for json value explicitly:

```
select id, slug, title->>'$.uk' as locale_title from blog_posts
order by locale_title collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```